# My menu doesnt work when i resize responsive page to mobile size:(

Tags: javascript, mobile, menu

I can't seem to figure out what is the problem when I resize my website down to mobile size.It is not a dropdown menu,yet it doesn't work on mobile version.Can someone take a look at my source code?I am trying all day,but nothing works.It is all great on computer but nothing happens on the resized version.
Thank's in advance guys.

xlff.rs

Comment: Please please please :)

Comment: Did I miss the source in there or did you just forget to put it in?

Comment: I put the website link so that you guys can se the problem :/ I will add a code :)

Comment: Hm,can't add it now ,there s no way to change the question:/ Can you tako a look at cource from website?:(